# OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: 'runs/train/exp21/results.txt' in YoLoV7 in Google Colab Pro

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolov7

I am trying to train yolov7 model in Google Colab Pro for **110 epochs** but after 67 to 70 epochs I am getting this error - **Transport endpoint is not connected**.

I tried 6 times but every time I am getting this problem only.

[image]